# Neo4j cypher query to add relation to the existing node

Tags: neo4j

I have already created nodes in neo4j. among those nodes I am retrieving the node which has label "Suspicious" and creating a other node called "name" and creating relation ship between this node and "suspicious" node like as follows:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C://Datasets//data.csv' AS row WITH art
MATCH (n:Suspicious) where n.Name = art.`account`
MERGE (n1:person {Name1:art.`Name`})
CREATE (n)-[r:OWNER]->(n1)
return r
```

Now if I display only suspicious node with the following query:

```
MATCH (n:Suspicious) return n
```

Now when I double click on this suspicious node the node "name" which is having relationship with it has to populate. But it is not populating. Could anybody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your `WITH art` statement, which is where you lose all your `LOAD CSV` data. Get rid of it or change it to:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C://Datasets//data.csv' AS row AS art
MATCH (n:Suspicious) where n.Name = art.`account`
MERGE (n1:person {Name1:art.`Name`})
CREATE (n)-[r:OWNER]->(n1)
return r
```

or just use:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C://Datasets//data.csv' AS row
MATCH (n:Suspicious) where n.Name = row.`account`
MERGE (n1:person {Name1:row.`Name`})
CREATE (n)-[r:OWNER]->(n1)
return r
```

Comment: sorry, I did the mistake                                                                                              LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C://Datasets//data.csv' AS art WITH art
MATCH (n:Suspicious) where n.Name = art.`account`
MERGE (n1:person {Name1:art.`Name`})
CREATE (n)-[r:OWNER]->(n1)
return  r                                                                                                                this query I have given. still I am getting the problem

Comment: ```LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C://Datasets//data.csv' AS row AS art
MATCH (n:Suspicious) where n.Name = art.`account`
RETURN COUNT(*)
``` what does this return ?

Comment: it is returning the count of the suspicious nodes.